# Where is the options button in Rockplayer?

Tags: rockplayer

How do I open the options for the Rockplayer app? I need to get to the subtitle encoding menu so that my srt is supported (currently it looks like Chinese) but I can't find it. I see only the play/pause buttons, the screen resize button and the video info button. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

Try pressing your phone's Menu button.  That should bring up everything else you can do/look at/etc. that is not on-screen.